# How can I link to page with data-value value attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I have a webpage that I would like to link to. The web page contains a schedule with dates. Upon clicking a date, the page content changes to the schedule of that day.

How can I link to a schedule of that specific day. If I look at the source code, this is the link for the day:

```
<a class="schedule__date-btn active" href="#" data-value="1504828800" style="color:  ;">September 1, 2017</a>
```

Comment: You would need to dive deeper into the javascript to find the url that is being accessed. Does the web page happen to be publicly accessible so I could have a look?

Comment: Have a look at what script gets trigger `onclick`.

Comment: Is it like [this page](http://thinkgreenstone.com/register/schedule/)? There is some js processing here. You can't link to this action directly.

Comment: The page that vp_arth linked uses the same exact template that the website in question uses. I looked through the code and there is some AJAX processing going on.

Comment: Not even clear if this is your own page or on some other site. Take some time to read [ask]

Comment: Would a JSON response suffice?